# Database structure: Customers buy different items

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I have a table which stores all item information and its id. Now I want to create an table with all customers and log which item who bought. What is the best solution for this? I guess it is not very efficient if store it like this:

```
|customer_id | username | password | boughtproducts   |
| 1          | herbert  |123       |productid1,pid2...|
```

How would you do it?

Comment: The table you show does not look like a good solution. For example, what datatype is `boughtproducts`?

Comment: @Droider, I suggest looking into database normalisation (eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization ) - this should explain the answers offered so far, together with why they are a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler way to deal with this situation is the following:

Table Customer:
customer_id | username | password

Table Product:
product_id | productName | ...

Table Sales:
sale_id | customer_id | product_id | Time of sale

This way, using the table 'Sales', you will store all the sales of every customer and product.
The customer_id in 'Sales' is a foreign key from 'Customer' table, and product_id in 'Sales' is a foreign key from 'Product' table.

I hope this answered your question

Answer (score 2):

```
have one Customers Table // store details of the customers

have once Products Table // store details of the products

have one Customers_products Table

|primary_key|customer_id | product_id |
|           | 1          | 1          |
|           | 1          | 2          |
```

There is Many to Many Relationship between Customers and Products. One customer can buy many products, similarly one product can be bought by many customers. So standard way to implement many to many relationships, is to have one more table, and this new table will contain primary keys from both tables.

Primary Key can be AutoIncremented, or a `composite key` of both the foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous examples of this type of schema available on the web.

But in summary your DB may take the form of...

`Customer` table : One customer can have many..

`Order` table : One order can have many..

`OrderLine` table : One orderline will be related to one...

`Product` table. (And one `Product` will be related to may `OrderLine`s)

So `OrderLine` will contain a `ProductID` and `Quantity`. You can then `JOIN` tables and make a full `Order`.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually go with 2 more tables.  One for Customer and then a second for Products they bought  Like So:

Customer

CustomerID|Username|Password

PUrchases:

CustomerID|ProductID|Date| etc